# Multiple button calling same function and execute different method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have two buttons calling same function, and btnUpdate have to execute this function whereas btnsave no need to execute this method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Update_New() {
  if (document.getElementById("btnUpdate").value == 2) {
    var update_confrimation = confirm("Are you sure you want to Update?");
    if (update_confrimation == true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

CODE FOR BUTTONS

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="SAVE" OnClick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="return Update_New()" value="1" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="UPDATE" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" OnClientClick="return Update_New() " value="2" /
```

> WHEN I CLICK UPDATE ,NO ACTION TAKES PLACE
>   The problem which i get is VALUE IS NOT DEFINED in javascript(@document.getElementById("btnUpdate").value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this you can pass parameters to function when you call that function as shown below:

**HTML:**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="SAVE" OnClick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="return Update_New(true)" value="1" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="UPDATE" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" OnClientClick="return Update_New(false) " value="2" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Update_New(isnew) {
        if (!isnew) {
            var update_confrimation = confirm("Are you sure you want to Update?");
            if (update_confrimation == true) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Note:**  If you want to access server controls, you can access it as mentioned below:

```
document.getElementById('<%=btnUpdate.ClientID%>').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `asp` controls directly in javascript by using `document.getElementById()` you can refer this [blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd410598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for make it possible

Set the `ClientIDMode` property of the control to one of the following values:

1. AutoID
2. Static
3. Predictable
4. Inherit

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var seasonalSports = new Array("None selected",
                                 "Tennis",
                                 "Volleyball",
                                 "Baseball",
                                 "Skiing");

  function DisplaySport(x) {
      document.getElementById("SelectedSport").innerHTML
      = seasonalSports[x];
  }    
</script>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                  onchange="DisplaySport(this.selectedIndex);">
  <asp:ListItem Value="Select a season"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="Spring"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="Summer"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="Autumn"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="Winter"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="SelectedSport" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
</asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either set the `ClientIDMode` property of `btnUpdate` to Static

or

Use `getElementById("<%=btnUpdate.ClientID%>")`

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have accepted an answer and all of above answer are working properly but I am adding this to make you aware what mistake you have done. As per your shared mark-up which goes like this:-

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="SAVE" OnClick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="return Update_New()" value="1" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="UPDATE" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" OnClientClick="return Update_New() " value="2" /
```

You are using a property named as `value` here Asp.Net server control doesn't recognized this propety see this **MSDN** link [Button Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) even if you are specifying it as custom attribute but still it won't get rendered because Button `Text` property when gets rendered as HTML it becomes `value` so there a conflict. Here in your case it will be **Save/Update** instead of **1/2** respectively.

A better approach will be to use a `data-attribute` where you can save some data values for client use.

**HTML**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="SAVE" OnClick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick="return Update_New()" data-attr="1" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="UPDATE" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" OnClientClick="return Update_New()" data-attr="2" />
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Update_New(obj) {
        if (obj != undefined) {
            if (obj.dataset.attr == 2) {
                var update_confrimation = confirm("Are you sure you want to Update?");
                if (update_confrimation == true) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {

                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```